# How can I reset or clear the clipping mask associated with a CGContext?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm drawing to a CGContext and using a CGImageRef-based mask:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, _firstMaskImageRef);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
```

I have a second mask that I then want to switch to:

```
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, _secondMaskImageRef);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color); // color has changed FWIW
CGContextFillRect(context, rect); // as has rect
```

But, this intersects the two masks instead of replacing the first.

How do you (if you can) clear out or reset the clipping mask for a CGContext?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can save the graphics state before you set the clipping mask, and then reset it afterwards, like this:

```
CGContextSaveGState (context);
...Set your first clipping mask, fill it, etc.
CGContextRestoreGState (context);
...Do other stuff
```

Answer (score 7):

To reset the clipping mask, use:

```
CGContextResetClip(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Swift (3+?) use the following syntax instead:

```swift
context.saveGState()
// set your clipping mask, etc.
context.restoreGState()
// everything's back to normal
```